Using AppAuth library on Android but can't get valid AuthorizationResponse.fromIntent
I was trying to log in to a government website (Gov.br) using the AppAuth library on Android.
So I was taking help from one of my friends, I copied the class code from his code, but it still doesn't work fully for me.
This is what I get from logCat:
onNewIntent LoginGovActivity
Intent data: br.gov.sp.ged://ged/my-callback?state=xxxxxxxxsXs3b78sfa1Jg&session_state=xxxxxxxx-87c8-4f9f-a4d4-46b0ef05ed8c&code=xxxxxxxx-6abb-42ae-810b-1884550ba58e.a51820f7-87c8-4f9f-a4d4-46b0ef05ed8c.34375c15-d1ed-47d4-8eed-xxxxxxxxxxx
intent: Bundle[{com.android.browser.application_id=org.mozilla.firefox}]
ex: null
resp: null

My problem is the parameter "resp" and "ex" are always null for me.
It works for my friend, but it didn't work for me.
This is the class code:
class LoginGovActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

val CALLBACK_URL = "xxx" // change value to publish it here
val CLIENT_ID = "xxx" // change value to publish it here

var btnLoginGov: Button? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gov_login)

    btnLoginGov = findViewById<View>(R.id.login_gov) as Button

    btnLoginGov!!.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        Log.i(Constantes.DEV_DEBUG_TAG, "login gov br click v1")
        loginGovBrV1()
    })

}

private fun loginGovBrV1() {
    Log.i(Constantes.DEV_DEBUG_TAG,"teste v0")
    AuthorizationServiceConfiguration.fetchFromIssuer(
        Uri.parse("https://hmlsite/auth"),
        AuthorizationServiceConfiguration.RetrieveConfigurationCallback { serviceConfig, ex ->
            if (ex != null) {
                Log.e(Constantes.DEV_DEBUG_TAG, "Failed to fetch configuration: ${ex.message}")
                return@RetrieveConfigurationCallback
            }

            val authRequest = AuthorizationRequest.Builder(
                serviceConfig!!,
                CLIENT_ID,
                ResponseTypeValues.CODE,
                Uri.parse(CALLBACK_URL)
            )
                .setAdditionalParameters(Collections.singletonMap(
                    "prefersEphemeralSession",
                    "false"
                ))
                .setScope("openid")
                .build()

            Log.i(Constantes.DEV_DEBUG_TAG,"teste v1")

            val appAuthConfig = AppAuthConfiguration.Builder().setBrowserMatcher(AnyBrowserMatcher.INSTANCE).build()

            val pendingFlags = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
            } else {
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            }

            Log.i(Constantes.DEV_DEBUG_TAG,"teste v2")

            val authService = AuthorizationService(this, appAuthConfig)
            Log.i(Constantes.DEV_DEBUG_TAG,"teste v3")
            val pendingActivityLoginGov = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this,
                0,
                Intent(this, LoginGovActivity::class.java),
                pendingFlags
            )
            authService.performAuthorizationRequest(
                authRequest,
                pendingActivityLoginGov
            )
            Log.i(Constantes.DEV_DEBUG_TAG,"teste v4")



        }) // AuthorizationServiceConfiguration
}

override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)

    Log.i(Constantes.DEV_DEBUG_TAG, "onNewIntent LoginGovActivity")

    val dataString = intent.dataString
    Log.i(Constantes.DEV_DEBUG_TAG, "Intent data: $dataString")

    val resp = AuthorizationResponse.fromIntent(intent)
    val ex = AuthorizationException.fromIntent(intent)

    MyLog.i("intent: " + intent.data)
    MyLog.i("intent: " + intent.extras)
    MyLog.i("ex: " + ex)
    MyLog.i("resp: " + resp)
    
    if (resp != null) {
        startTokenExchange(resp)
    }

}

private fun startTokenExchange(resp1: AuthorizationResponse) {
    MyLog.i("startTokenExchange call")
    Log.i(Constantes.DEV_DEBUG_TAG, "startTokenExchange call")
    AuthorizationService(this).performTokenRequest(resp1.createTokenExchangeRequest())
    { resp, ex ->
        if(resp != null) {
            // do some processing
        }
    }
}

}

This is my android manifest activity:
<activity
        android:name=".main.activity.LoginGovActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="br.gov.sp.ged"
                android:host="ged"
                android:path="/my-callback" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

My friend android manifest activity is this:
<activity    android:name=".ui.activity.login.LoginInfoActivity"    android:exported="true"    android:label="@string/app_title"    android:launchMode="singleTask"    android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"     />

I put an intentFilter on my AndroidManifest.xml file, otherwise when I call the function and put my login and password on the government site, it does come back to the app.
Any help is appreciatted to understand why my the code "AuthorizationResponse.fromIntent(intent)" is always null
